# UITapGestureRecognizer selector not called beyond screen height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I saw several questions being asked about UITapGestureRecognizer selector not getting called, but I seem to be encountering something a bit different than what other folks have asked.  I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView and I need to detect taps on the image.

The image at first is loaded and the UIImageView is set to 568 pixels tall to show the image ScaledAspectFill and taps work fine.  When I detect a double tap, I set the scaling to 1.0 and the UIImageView is resized to 960 pixels tall, which happens to be the image's unscaled size.

Now the fun begins.  The taps work fine whenever the locationInView.y is within location 568.  However, if I tap lower in the image, my selector does not get called.  Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Red

---

I have set userInteractionEnabled in the storyboard... as proof by taps calling the selector when locationInView.y is less than 568 as well as the double taps being recognized.

Here is the code snippet that sets up the tap recognizer## Heading ##:

```
_tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[_tapGesture setDelegate:self];
[_tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[_theImageView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
```

---

**SOLUTION**:  I discovered if you make the view really tall inside the story board (taller than any image I might load), even when I programmatically shrink the image view, the tap is recognized. But the converse encountered the problem. If I made the image view small and grew it programmatically, the tap was not recognized.

Comment: You add the gesture recognizer on a image and want to get gesture from outside of the image? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear.  The UIImageView is inside a UIScrollView.  So the user should be allowed to scroll down lower on the image and tap on the lower parts.  The user would still be tapping on the image.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered if you make the view really tall inside the story board (taller than any image I might load), even when I programmatically shrink the image view, the tap is recognized.  But the converse encountered the problem.  If I made the image view small and grew it programmatically, the tap was not recognized.